# Como enviar los datos de un componente a otro al hacer click en un botón. React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, props

Tengo una consulta, tengo una tabla en la cual se muestran los resultados de la API de pokemon y lo que necesito es que al hacer click en un boton obtenga los datos de la fila, bueno hasta aquí todo bien, ahora lo que quiero hacer es que esos datos que obtengo los envie a otro componente ya que en la tabla se mostrara poca información y cuando se haga click quiero que se muestren mas datos en una tarjeta, pero mi pregunta es: como puedo enviar esos datos a otro componente para renderizarlos?

**Tabla con la info**

```
export const Lista = (props) => {

    const [, setPokeSelec] = useState({
        id: '',
    })

    const seleccionarFila = ( poke ) => {

        setPokeSelec( poke );
        console.log(poke);
    }
    
    return (

        <>
            <TableRow key={ props.info.id }>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    { props.info.id }
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{ props.info.name }</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{ props.info.abilities[0].ability.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                    <img src={ props.info.sprites.front_default } alt={ props.info.name } style={{ height: 60 }} />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                    <Button 
                        variant="contained" 
                        color="primary" 
                        size="small" 
                        onClick={ () => seleccionarFila( props.info ) }
                    >
                        Seleccionar
                    </Button>
                    </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Este es el componente donde quiero mostrar los datos seleccionados**

```
export const Informacion = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={ classes.margen } >
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <Card className={classes.root}>
                    <CardMedia
                        className={classes.cover}
                        image={pika}
                        title="Live from space album cover"
                    />
                    <div className={classes.details}>
                        <CardContent className={classes.content}>

                        <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                            Pikachu
                        </Typography>

                        <Divider/>

                        <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textPrimary">
                            Tipo:
                        </Typography>

                        <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">
                            Electrico
                        </Typography>

                        <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textPrimary">
                            Primera habilidad:
                        </Typography>

                        <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">
                            Impactrueno
                        </Typography>

                        <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textPrimary">
                            Segunda habilidad:
                        </Typography>

                        <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">
                            Rayo
                        </Typography>

                        </CardContent>
                    </div>
                </Card>
            </Box>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Como podria resolverlo? Los datos al hacer click ya los veo en consola.

Saludos y gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma sería pasarle al componente la prop con la el objeto que debe mostrar la información.

```
 export const Informacion = ({ pokemon }) => { ... }
```

Esta prop pokemon es algo que va a cambiar, por lo tanto es un estado de la aplicación que debe guardarse en el componente padre. Como el otro componente son filas de una tabla, lo mejor sería guardar el estado en el componente tabla en sí mismo y que se muestre de forma condicional el componente si existe algo seleccionado.

```
export const Pokes = () => {

    const [ pokeSelec, setPokeSelec] = useState({})

    const seleccionarFila = ( poke ) => {    
        setPokeSelec( poke );            
    }
return ( 
<>
       <Container maxWidth="md">
           <PokemonApi seleccionarFila={seleccionarFila} />                
           { pokeSelec && <Informacion pokemon={pokeSelec} />} 
        </Container>        
<>)
```

Debería actualizar pokemon api, o si lo quieres mñas pulido usar un useContext:

```
export const PokemonApi = ({seleccionarFila}) => {
....
...
{ filtrarPokemons && filtrarPokemons().map((infos, name) => <Lista 
key={name} info={infos} seleccionarFila={seleccionarFila}/>) }
```

Por último solo deberías pasar a tu componente fila la función seleccionarFila para poder cambiar el estado de la tabla.

```
export const Lista = ({ seleccionarFila, ...props}) => {...
```

Lo de arriba funcionaría pero todo esto se puede realizar con un contexto y quedaría más limpio, se recomienda crear el contexto en un fichero aparte y crear un hook específico para recuperarlo, pero de la forma más simple:

```
export const PokeContext = React.createContext();

export const Pokes = () => {
    
        const [ pokeSelec, setPokeSelec] = useState({})        
        
    return ( 
    <>
       <PokeContext.Provider value={{pokeSelec, setPokeSelec}}>
           <Container maxWidth="md">
               <PokemonApi />                
               { pokeSelec && <Informacion />} 
            </Container>   
       </PokeContext.Provider>     
    <>)
```

Los otros archivos debeérian recuperar el contexto para usarlo:

```
 export const Informacion = () => {
    const {pokeSelec, setPokeSelec} = useContext(PokeContext)
  ....
  }


export const Lista = (props) => { 
     const {pokeSelec, setPokeSelec} = useContext(PokeContext)
      ....
  }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! El problema es que cuando llamo a mi componente **Informacion** en el componente **Lista** se renderiza la tarjeta 5 veces sobre la tabla, aun no entiendo muy bien de que manera podria evitar eso.

Comment: Dado que el componente lista son varias filas si pones el componente informacion en la lista se generará por cada lista uno, por eso te recomendaba llamar al componente información en el componente tabla padre del que nacen los lista  y hacerlo que solo salga si el estado no está vacío.

Comment: Dado que en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504427/how-to-send-the-data-from-one-component-to-another-component-when-i-press-a-butt has actualizado la información, la forma es poner el estado en el componente pokes y pasar el estado a informacion y el la funcion de cambiar PokemonApi.

Comment: Que tal! No te entendi muy bien, lo que dices es que el estado: const [ pokeSelec, setPokeSelec] = useState({}) Lo debo de mover al componente Pokes y luego enviarselo al de información, pero la funcion de cambiar PokemonApi no comprendi que debo hacer con ella

Comment: Por si quieres tener un mejor vistazo del codigo aqui esta el repositorio https://github.com/AndresW99/Poke-API como ultima opción utilizare redux, pero quiero hacerlo sin el.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta dado a la ampliación de información, puedes usar Redux para mantener estados, pero no es necesario, el hook useContext permite lo mismo, lo eh añadido a la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!! Justo ayer decidi implementar context, al presionar el boton envio la información al context y luego la renderizo en la carta. Marcaré tu respuesta ya que es la forma mas facil de hacerlo.